# HikariConfig database connection not close in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

I am using spring boot with Hikari. But my database connection is not close. It is increasing. Here is my configuration.

```
public DataSource getConVentionalConnection()  {        

    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setJdbcUrl(mydd);
    config.setUsername("user");
    config.setPassword("user");
    config.setMinimumIdle(5);
    config.setMaximumPoolSize(500);
    config.setConnectionTimeout(300);
    config.setMaxLifetime(300);
    config.setIdleTimeout(300);
    config.setKeepaliveTime(300);
    config.setConnectionTestQuery("SELECT 1 FROM DUAL");
    config.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    return new HikariDataSource(config);
   
}
```

What is wrong with my code...Please help me...

Comment: This method will create a new connection pool every time it is called; that's not what you want. Try this: https://www.javadevjournal.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hikari/